# iOS: UnitTesting: Cocoa Touch Framework: Pass App's info plist data in XCTest

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, xctest, xctestcase

We have developed cocoa touch framework for our Apps. We have integrated some third party libraries in it. One of the third party library needs the access key which the app should have it in the `Info.plist`.

While writing unit tests for our developed framework, I can't able to test my few logics which has the dependancy of the 3rd party framework which needs the access key for initialization. But the access key should be passed via App's `Info.plist`.

Kindly let me know how to pass the Accesskey for my unit testing.

FYI, My cocoa touch framework has many third party libraries integrated via cocoa pods

Lets say

```
class Sample{
  func someMethod() -> Int{
     let someObj = ThridPartyClass() // The definition is inside the Pod
   return someObj.status
  }
}
```

Here ThridPartyClass will check access key and NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription in Info.plist, if it is not there it will throw an error.

Comment: "This application’s Info.plist file must include a NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription.  --- How to include this in XCTest?

Comment: Please show us code examples demonstrating the problem you face.

Comment: @JonReid, I added the code samples. Kindly check